# Cassandra DB - Bind Variables

Tags: cassandra, bind

How to use bind variables in a select statement.

1) When I am using it directly it is retrieving the values as below.

```
select event_hour 
from stage_insight.insight_hourly_ts 
where tag_id='UP247490.UPSYSCPWLV001A'  LIMIT 1;
```

2) How to use dynmacially?

```
select event_hour 
from stage_insight.insight_hourly_ts 
where tag_id = ? ;
```

For the second one, an error is displayed like, wrong amount of bind variables....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to prepare your statement first. In python, try the following (similar approach applies to other languages)

```
ps=session.prepare("SELECT event_hour FROM stage_insight.insight_hourly_ts WHERE tag_id = ?")
session.execute(ps, ['UP247490.UPSYSCPWLV001A'])
```

Check the driver documentation for the relevant language, i.e. for [python](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#id2) or for [java](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/manual/statements/prepared/).

PS: you can't play with prepared statement in cqlsh. You have to use a driver.

Comment: Hey Chris, I am working with DataStax DevCenter. So, here I am trying to fetch the values directly from CassandraDB.                                                                                       1) Rather than using Python can't we fetch directly from DataStax?                                                                                              2)How to fetch values from two tables at one go?

Comment: I don't think you can do prepared statement from Devcenter